# Run a SQL Server job until it succeeds

Tags: sql, sql-server, jobs

I have a SQL Server job that has run for almost 2 years.

It's connecting to a bad Oracle database that keeps disconnecting, it always fails due to that. And when I run it again after 10 or 15 minutes, it works successfully. I'm getting bored of checking it every day...

Is there a way that make the job run to connect to that Oracle source until it succeeds, or another job that looks over this job status and if it failed, then it runs it again until it succeeds?

Comment: Try to troubleshoot the connectivity. If you want to try invoking the job again and again for success, you can configure retry attempts accordingly.

Comment: I would try and fix the problem with poor connection. There's no need to do it that way. Any other solution is just a hack and a sticking plaster.

Comment: you can set retry attempts and retry interval for that step, see more here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/job-step-properties-new-job-step-advanced-page

Answer (score 0):

A solution we are using is something like this:

Wrap your Oracle query in an SSIS package, and after the query, have the package update a SQL table that keeps either a history of executions, or just a single row that tracks the last time the job ran successfully.  In short, if the Oracle query was successful, then put something in a table saying the query ran successfully today.   If it was not successful, then don't put anything in the table for today.

Then at the beginning of the package, BEFORE the Oracle query, check to see if the query has been run successfully today.   If it has already run successfully, then do nothing and exit the package.   If it has not run successfully today, then go ahead and try to run it, following the post-query steps described above.  If you have any other conditions about when the package should run (like "only after 10 am" or anything like that) you would include that logic here.

Finally, schedule the job to call the package, and schedule to run every 15 minutes, or however often you like.   It will try every 15 minutes until it runs successfully, and after that it will stop doing anything until the next day.

As a bonus, you can use this same package and job to initiate all tasks that you want handled the same way.  You just need to keep meta data about all these tasks in your history/metadata table.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative is to create the job step and leave it unscheduled, and create an ssis job that acts as the master to all your jobs and it runs every minute checking all job steps from a config table that have yet to succeed today and any it finds execute using sp_start_job.

if they do run successfully log the stats to a log table and this prevents them ever being launched again until the next day. This prevents all yours jobs needing to be scheduled every 15 minutes etc, they launch asap, and you can add extra logic to handle dependencies, number parallel running, importance level etc, start time, latest start time, max number to retty etc